# JS: Why is my variable being assigned a function instead of calling the function?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to set some random coordinates on a map. I wrote the console.log line to see if it was successfully picking numbers, but it's telling me that everything in my `destinations` array is NaN.

It looks like it's assigning the Math.random function to the variable instead of calling Math.random and giving it the number it returns. Anyone know what's up?

```
var nodeCount = 10
var mapSize = 100;

var destinations = new Array(nodeCount);
for (var i = 0; i < nodeCount; i++) {
    destinations[i] = new Array(2);
}

var generateDestinations = function(nodeCount) {
    for (var i=0; i<nodeCount; i++) {
        destinations[i][0] = Math.floor(Math.random*mapSize); //sets x-coord
        destinations[i][1] = Math.floor(Math.random*mapSize); //sets y-coord
        console.log(destinations);
    }
};
generateDestinations(nodeCount);
```

Comment: To call a function you need  parentheses after the function name. `Math.random()*mapSize`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Math.random()` is a function, so it needs to be invoked with the call-operator:

```
Math.floor(Math.random() * mapSize);
//                    ^^
```

Same goes for the line below it.

---

Moreover, you can use the array literal syntax instead of calling the constructor. It's much cleaner and more expressive:

```
var destinations = [];
for (var i = 0; i < nodeCount; i++) {
    destinations[i] = [];
}
```

Comment: I was originally looking for some solution to create each spot in the array as it went through the for loop, but I don't know how to call out the second position of the array. 

I tried changing the first loop to the one you provided, but I'm getting a syntax error because it's not understanding when I use the second bracketed number.

`destinations[i][0] = Math.floor(Math.random()*mapSize); //sets x-coord`

Comment: Shoot, I left in the `new Array` part so the error read like:

`var destinations = new Array[];
                             ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ]`

I fixed it though, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_random.asp

try this, looks like your defining a max value but not a min, (I am assuming you want a number between 0 and mapSize)

```
    //                         \/ max value
    Math.floor((Math.random()*mapSize) + 0);
    //                                   /\ min value
```

also Math.random is a function so its

```
Math.random()
```

Comment: How does adding zero help?

Comment: adding zero is the min value, so you could really put 90 or anything you want.  Since mapSize = 100, then this would return a value from 0 to 100

Comment: My point is that adding zero doesn't actually do anything - you get the same result without it. Note that if you used a positive number instead of zero that would increase both the minimum _and_ maximum possible values, since you add it after doing the multiplication.